# Add line breaks in Category description via enter

Tags: categories

My client wants to ad line breaks in category description via keyboard enter. In the editor the white space is added, but it is not shown on the website.

I can add it with `&nbsp;` but I have to be able to do it by enter key.

I tried commenting out this in `default-filters.php`:

```
foreach ( array( 'pre_term_description', 'pre_link_description', 'pre_link_notes', 'pre_user_description' ) as $filter ) {
    add_filter( $filter, 'wp_filter_kses' );
}
```

But it didn't work. Neither adding this to my `functions.php`:

```
$filters = array('pre_term_description', 'pre_link_description', 'pre_link_notes', 'pre_user_description');
foreach ( $filters as $filter ) {
    remove_filter($filter, 'wp_filter_kses');
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: off-topic as wordpress doesn't have a visual editor for the category description, therefor you are using a plugin and we can't guess what exactly the plugin does and how to adjust it to your needs.... unless you meant something else when you wrote "visual editor"

Comment: @MarkKaplun Sorry, I think I misused the term. By `visual editor` I meant the space where you enter the description of the category. I don't have any plugins installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard PHP function [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for that

```
echo nl2br(category_description( $category_id ));
```

Comment: better approach is to use wordpress builtin function wpautop (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a built-in Wordpress function for that: [wpautop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop). It's more flexible than nl2br.

Use the Wordpress function like so:

```
wpautop(category_description( $category_id ) );
```

It will change the new and empty lines into paragraph tags automatically.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a bit more information as to how this function works and why it may solve the original problem? Looks like this may have been auto-flagged as low-quality because of its short content.

Comment: it's an "answer" not "question". and not every "auto" thing is efficient, that's why humans should use their brain before down-voting :)

Comment: While it's true that no all "auto things" are efficient - it doesn't make your answer any less low quality. As it stands now it's a [Code Only](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) answer which usually isn't well received. Answers should generally be informative and contain all the information needed without having to look much further. I'm sure if you used the edit button above and added some more information on the functions and an explanation on how they work your answer would probably be more well received.

Comment: ok please edit it to make it more informative. you can copy the wpautop functions code from wordpress itself here too to make it lengthier to fulfil the "autocheck" :)

Comment: also plz elaborate how is this different from the "size" of answer by the 9557 reputation user :) anyway, stay blessed

Comment: You have the ability to edit your own answer by click the `edit` link toward the bottom of the answer content. You're right it's not very different but that doesn't mean you can't improve it. For example - you could easily explain what the function does and provide a link to the codex or developer resources. The reason you were singled out is because it's a new answer to an old question without much content which is why I provided a comment to try and be helpful.

Comment: well i wanted to keep it "precise" but for your happiness, i've made it boring and uselessly lengthy now :)

Comment: Why is better to use a Wordpress function than a PHP function? :-/

Comment: why're you using wordpress if you want to use php functions only and not wordpress ones? :)

Comment: Wordpress runs on PHP. The actual reason to use wpautop is that it's more flexible.